# Find strings from text same pattern as given words

Tags: python, regex

Here are some words like

```
'X201i'
'B-442N-5'
'00.55005.001'
...
```

I want write a python script learn the pattern from given words.
fixed length, same special character at the same position, same type(digit or letter) at same position.

So I can find out the similar strings  like

```
'B304D'  => 'letter|number|number|number|letter'
'e-472N-5' =>'letter|-|number|number|number|letter|-|number'
```

any suggestion or hints?

Comment: My hint: use an editor to create the python program and try it out on the input that you have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define two seperate patterns for matching both type of formats.

```
r'^(?:[A-Za-z]\d{3}[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]-\d{3}[A-Za-z]-\d)$'
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['X201i',
'B-442N-5',
'00.55005.001']
>>> [i for i in s if re.match(r'^(?:[A-Za-z]\d{3}[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]-\d{3}[A-Za-z]-\d)$', i)]
['X201i', 'B-442N-5']
```

`[A-Za-z]` matches a letter and `\d` matches a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the words into regular expressions and then use those:

```
>>> import re
>>> words = 'X201i', 'B-442N-5', '00.55005.001'
>>> for word in words:
        pattern = ''.join([re.escape(c), '\d', '[A-Za-z]'][c.isdigit() - c.isalpha()]
                          for c in word) + '$'
        print pattern, 'matches', ', '.join(filter(re.compile(pattern).match, words))

[A-Za-z]\d\d\d[A-Za-z]$ matches X201i
[A-Za-z]\-\d\d\d[A-Za-z]\-\d$ matches B-442N-5
\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d$ matches 00.55005.001
```